# Is there a Python open source equivalent to Ontop?

Tags: library, python, rdf, sparql

I found [this Java based library Ontop](https://github.com/ontop/ontop) that can query relational databases as Virtual RDF Knowledge Graphs using SPARQL.

Is there a Python equivalent for this?